# How to unnest my JSON data object and create a simplified JSON using Snowflake?

Tags: arrays, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, google-analytics-4

My current JSON object looks like this:

```
-- create a sample table
create or replace table json_example(v variant);
-- create sample json record
insert into json_example
select parse_json(
    '[
      {
        "key": "variable_a",
        "value": {
          "double_value": null,
          "float_value": null,
          "int_value": null,
          "string_value": "https://example.com"
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "variable_b",
        "value": {
          "double_value": null,
          "float_value": null,
          "int_value": 2,
          "string_value": null
        }
      }
     ]');
```

And this is the simplified JSON that I am trying to achieve:

```
  {
    "variable_a": "https://example.com",
    "variable_b": 2
  }
```

How can I get the simplified JSON from the multilevel JSON object?

This is how I started to think:

```
select value:key::string as key, value:value:string_value::varchar as value
from json_example, lateral flatten(input => v)
union all
select value:key::string as key, value:value:int_value::varchar as value
from json_example, lateral flatten(input => v)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just to be clear, you're thinking there should only be one non-null value per item in the array, and you want a single object mapping the key for each item to the first non-null value in that item?

Answer (score 2):

So if you want everthing thing to be JSON text you can:

```
WITH data as (
select parse_json(
    '[
      {
        "key": "variable_a",
        "value": {
          "double_value": null,
          "float_value": null,
          "int_value": null,
          "string_value": "https://example.com"
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "variable_b",
        "value": {
          "double_value": null,
          "float_value": null,
          "int_value": 2,
          "string_value": null
        }
      }
     ]') as json
)
SELECT f.value:key::text as t_key
    ,try_to_double(f.value:value:double_value::text) as d_val
    ,try_to_double(f.value:value:float_value::text) as f_val
    ,try_to_number(f.value:value:int_value::text) as n_val
    ,f.value:value:string_value::text as s_val
    ,coalesce(d_val::text, f_val::text, n_val::text, s_val) as c_val
    ,object_construct(t_key, c_val) as obj
FROM DATA, lateral flatten(input=>json) f
```

| T_KEY D_VAL | F_VAL | N_VAL | S_VAL | C_VAL | OBJ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| variable_a |  |  |  | https://example.com | https://example.com |
| variable_b |  |  | 2 |  | 2 |

Which then shows us how to build a CASE statement, and build clean native objects like:

```
SELECT 
    case 
        when not is_null_value(f.value:value:double_value) 
            then object_construct(f.value:key::text, try_to_double(f.value:value:double_value::text))
        when not is_null_value(f.value:value:float_value) 
            then object_construct(f.value:key::text, try_to_double(f.value:value:float_value::text))
        when not is_null_value(f.value:value:int_value) 
            then object_construct(f.value:key::text, try_to_number(f.value:value:int_value::text))
        else 
            object_construct(f.value:key::text, f.value:value:string_value::text)
    end obj
FROM DATA, lateral flatten(input=>json) f
```

| OBJ |
| --- |
| { "variable_a": "https://example.com" } |
| { "variable_b": 2 } |

Which can be turned into a single object like so:

```
SELECT 
    object_agg(f.value:key, 
    case 
        when not is_null_value(f.value:value:double_value) 
            then try_to_double(f.value:value:double_value::text)
        when not is_null_value(f.value:value:float_value) 
            then try_to_double(f.value:value:float_value::text)
        when not is_null_value(f.value:value:int_value) 
            then try_to_number(f.value:value:int_value::text)
        else 
            f.value:value:string_value
    end
   ) as obj
FROM DATA, lateral flatten(input=>json) f
```

| OBJ |
| --- |
| { "variable_a": "https://example.com", "variable_b": 2 } |

Answer (score 1):

There are three parts to this:

1. flatten the original JSON array and select the values you want from it
2. create new JSON objects based on the resulting row values.
3. combine the JSON objects into a single object.

```sql
with json_example(json) as (
  select parse_json(
      '[
        {
          "key": "variable_a",
          "value": {
            "double_value": null,
            "float_value": null,
            "int_value": null,
            "string_value": "https://example.com"
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "variable_b",
          "value": {
            "double_value": null,
            "float_value": null,
            "int_value": 2,
            "string_value": null
          }
        }
       ]'
  )
),
flattened_rows as
(
      select v.value:key::string as key, 
        v.value:value:int_value::int as int_value,
        v.value:value:string_value::string as string_value
        -- other values here
    from json_example, lateral flatten(input => json) as v
)
,
simplified_json as 
(
  select
    case when int_value is not null then object_construct(key, int_value)::variant
    else object_construct(key, string_value)
    end as json
  from flattened_rows
)
select object_agg(j.key, j.value)
from simplified_json, lateral flatten(input => json) AS j
;
```

`flattened_rows` looks like this:

| KEY | INT_VALUE | STRING_VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| variable_a |  | https://example.com |
| variable_b | 2 |  |

`simplified_json` looks like this:

| JSON |
| --- |
| { "variable_a": "https://example.com" } |
| { "variable_b": 2 } |

Final results:

| OBJ |
| --- |
| { { "variable_a": "https://example.com", "variable_b": 2 } |

### Update

I updated the answer above to incorporate the `object_agg` approach Simeon found. My original answer involved creating a JavaScript UDTF that leveraged `Object.assign` to combine the json objects.